# How can I use generate elements to only fill the screen using Mui Grid in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Mui Grid and want to generate fixed size grid elements to fill the screen (both height and width) but I don't know how to do that.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dawn-6senlm?file=/demo.tsx) is a CodeSandbox link of something basic I am working with. In this example, I hard coded it to render 20 elements. I instead want it to account for the screen size, padding, margin, etc. to programmatically determine how many elements to render. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no way for MUI Grid to auto stretch all element to fill your screen. You may want to make a function to calculate fluid grids and spacing depend on your array length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible using `Grid`, but with plain JavaScript, you should be able to calculate the number of elements to render to fill a page and an event listener on `"resize"` to continually calculate the proper number of elements to render to completely fill the page width.

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-span-one-row-only-16w8qk?file=/demo.tsx:205-1012)

```js
const itemWidth = 100;
const gridGap = 10;

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  textAlign: "center",
  width: `${itemWidth}px`,
  height: "100px"
}));

export default function ResponsiveGrid() {
  const [numOfEl, setNumOfEl] = useState(
    Math.floor(window.innerWidth / (itemWidth + gridGap))
  );

  function getNumberOfElements() {
    setNumOfEl(Math.floor(window.innerWidth / (itemWidth + gridGap)));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", getNumberOfElements);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", getNumberOfElements);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid container sx={{ gap: `${gridGap}px` }}>
      {Array.from(Array(numOfEl)).map((_, index) => (
        <Grid key={index}>
          <Item>{index}</Item>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Edit: I only calculated the number for the width, but you get the idea.